# Not sure how to reverse my stack?

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

I am trying to write a program that implements a stack using linked lists, accepts unlimited words from the user until the word 'end' is entered, push each word onto the stack, Print to the user that youre done accepting words and you're about to list the sentence in reverse, and pop each word to the user so that they appear in reverse order from which they were entered. 
I have my code written but I think something may be wrong with my pop function because it is not printing in reverse order. Just the order I entered the information in, which means it is not popping, right? I am not sure.

So I just need help figuring out how to 
-pop each word to the user so that they appear in reverse order from which they were entered

Thanks!
Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
class node
{
      public:
             class node *next;
             string data;
};

class stack : public node
{
            node *head;
            int tos;
      public:
             stack()
             {
                 tos=-1;
             }
             void push(string x)
             {
                 if (tos < 0 )
                 {
                     head =new node;
                     head->next=NULL;
                     head->data=x;
                     tos ++;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     node *temp,*temp1;
                     temp=head;

                     tos++;
                     while(temp->next != NULL)
                          temp=temp->next;
                     temp1=new node;
                     temp->next=temp1;
                     temp1->next=NULL;
                     temp1->data=x;
                 }
             }
             void display()
             {
                  node *temp;
                  temp=head;
                  if (tos < 0)
                  {
                      cout <<" stack under flow";
                      return;
                  }
                  while(temp != NULL)
                  {
                      cout <<temp->data<< " ";
                      temp=temp->next;
                  }
              }
              void pop()
              {
                  node *temp;
                  temp=head;
                  if( tos < 0 )
                  {
                      cout <<"stack under flow";
                      return;
                  }
                  tos--;
                  while(temp->next->next!=NULL)
                  {
                      temp=temp->next;
                  }
                  temp->next=NULL;
              }    
};
main()
{
    stack s1;
    string input;

    while (input != "end"){
        cout <<"\n enter a element";
        cin >> input;
        s1.push(input);
    }
    s1.pop();


    s1.display();

    exit(0);    
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: If this is supposed to be a **stack**, your insertion logic makes no sense. Stacks are LIFO. meaning the only pointer you need to mess with on a *push* is the head pointer; **ever**. Your node node next-ptr points to the current head, then head is set to the new node.

Comment: (As far as reversing anything goes.)
All you need is one temporary node. Find out how many entries are in the vector. Then, you loop. Take the node[0] and assign it to temp. Then take node[last] and assign it to node[0], then set node[last] = temp.

Comment: Your question is tagged C++ but you `#include <stdlib.h>` and other stuff.  In C++ we have `std::stack<std::string>` if you are allowed to use it.

Comment: its also worth noting `stack` has no business inheriting from `node`, and `tos` isn't needed at all. You know if you're about to underflow your stack during a pop/top/display because `head` will be null (i.e. nothing to pop).

Answer (score -1):

```
int display(node * head)
{
      if(head)
      {
            display(head->next);
            cout<< head->data <<endl;
      }
}
```

This display function will print your stack in the reverse order.